# Changing Object to Integer with a $ Sign in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am reading data as a dataframe using pandas.

```
spend = pd.read_csv("Direct Spend.csv", encoding='unicode_escape', low_memory=False)
```

One of the column is an amount variable which per dtype shows as *Object*. To run a summary statistics on this variable i am trying to change this into an integer as below:

```
spend['Actual_PO']=spend['Actual_PO'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

This shows an error:

> `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' $ '`

After looking at the data i see it has a `$` simple and I removed it using this code:

```
spend['Actual_PO'] = spend['Actual_PO'].replace({'\$':''}, regex = True)
```

This changes however it still shows as Object for this variable. Similarly there are other error message as:

> `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1,517 '`

```
spend['Actual_PO'] = spend['Actual_PO'].replace({',':''}, regex = True
```

I have removed the 1,517 as well but now the error is:

> `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Is there a better way to convert the object which has `$` sign, space, comma in numbers etc. to an integer to run a summary statistics on the variable. The data has been downloaded from SAP database

Comment: `1,517` in not a valid float number. Should be: `1.517`

Comment: With a regular expression you can remove anything that isn't a digit. About the empty string you have to care separately.

Comment: `spend['Actual_PO'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int)`

Comment: spend['Actual_PO'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int): still gives the error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default empty values to zeros:

```
spend['Actual_PO'] = spend['Actual_PO'].str.replace(r'\D+','').replace(r'^\s*$', '0', regex=True).astype(int)
```

So,

- `.str.replace(r'\D+','')` removes all non-digits
- `.replace(r'^\s*$', '0', regex=True)` replaces blank values with `0`
- `.astype(int)` converts all to int type.